# How to wrap a line in label in iphone?

Tags: iphone, word-wrap, label

I am new to iphone development .I want to wrap up the text in the label.I want to wrap up to a particular position in the label.Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 theLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
 theLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

That'll let it wrap an arbitrary number of lines. If you want to limit them, and have it truncate with a “...”, then set the `numberOfLines` property to that value.

Answer (score 4):

Set "Line breaks" in Interface Builder ( http://drp.ly/d3K65 ) to "Word Wrap" and increase height of the UILabel.

You can do the same thing (or even more complex) in the code, see UILabel reference http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html

Comment: You also need to change 'Lines' in IB to zero (0)